# Question about opinion-based answers

Tags: discussion, primarily-opinion-based, comics

I posted [a question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96889/how-would-you-build-a-power-plant) about the best way to use fictional characters to generate power. I was looking forward to all the comic book wonks battling over the best scenario. But it was put on hold. Is this really an opinion-based answer issue?

Comment: You have enough rep to [post in chat](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat), why not take the discussion there?

Comment: @JasonBaker Because Meta is a perfectly cromulent place to get feedback on posts.

Comment: @Keen Agreed, but not what I meant. I maybe should have said "why not pose your question there?"

Answer (score 6):

The problem with this one is that there's no "right" answer. Superman can lift a near-infinite amount, the human Torch can generate a near-infinite amount of heat, etc etc.

Your meta question hits the nail on the head perfectly;

> I was looking forward to all the comic book wonks **battling over the
>   best scenario.**

We're not a discussion board, we're a Q&A site.

---

If I can quote from the [FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

> *Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and
>   push other questions off the front page.*

and

> *If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to
>   participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be
>   asking here*

and from [Real Questions Have Answers](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)

> Constructive subjective questions ....  are more than just mindless
>   social fun.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Just getting the hang of the site! I still believe that there is a right answer, but I recognize that it is just "mindless social fun". Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Social fun is fine, mindless isn't :-)

Comment: Any way I can clear the bad karma? It was an honest mistake.

Comment: @DanBurden - Downvotes on meta don't mean the same thing as they do on the main site. They just mean "I don't agree". They also don't count toward your main rep score.

Comment: Good to know! How about the original post?

Comment: @DanBurden - Ah well, you're stuck with that unless you delete it.